# reload TableView when the app comeback from a modalView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Basically this is the problem... I can't reload the data of the table view when I comeback from a modal view.

I try to reload data from the table view but the result is not effects.

Any idea? please...

Comment: Please post the code for what you have tried.

Comment: You have given us very little to work with but it sounds like when you dismiss the modal view you just need to refetch your data, then call `[tableview reloadData]`

Comment: +1 to both PengONe and Joe for my exact first thoughts. lol

Answer (score 1):

Your main view controller will get a `viewWillAppear` call when the modal view is dismissed (or for any other reason the view is about to appear).  So just implement call `reloadData` on your table at that point, like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```